# Python History and Design: Why issubclass() instead of rich comparisons?

Tags: python, computer-science, language-design, language-history

In Python, the comparison operators -- `<`, `<=`, `==`, `!=`, `>`, `>=` -- can be implemented to mean whatever is relevant to the implementing class. In Python 2 that was done by overriding `__cmp__`, and in Python 3 by overriding `__lt__` and friends. What is the advantage of having an `issubclass()` built-in method instead of allowing for expressions such as `bool < int` (true), `int < object` (true), `int <= int`, or `int < float` (false). In particular, I'll note that classes ordered by `issubclass()` constitutes a [partially ordered set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) in the mathematical sense.

The Python 3 equivalent of what I'm thinking would look like what's below. This code doesn't replace `issubclass()` (though looping over the MRO would accomplish that, right?). However, wouldn't this be more intuitive?

```python
@functools.total_ordering
class Type(type):
    "Metaclass whose instances (which are classes) can use <= instead issubclass()"
    def __lt__(self, other):
        try:
            return issubclass(self, other) and self != other
        except TypeError: # other isn't a type or tuple of types
            return NotImplemented
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, tuple): # For compatibility with __lt__
            for other_type in other:
                if type(self) is type(other_type):
                    return False
            return True
        else:
            return type(self) is type(other)
```

**Actual Question:** What is the advantage of having an issubclass() built-in method instead of allowing for expressions such as bool < int (true), int < object (true), int <= int, or int < float (false).

Comment: There's no particular reason. It just isn't, probably because these sorts of comparisons are largely discouraged anyway (you should be using inheritance and uniform interfaces).

Comment: So basically you're asking why they used a descriptive name instead of overloading the operators in a way that's probably not obvious to most people? (Disclaimer: *I* think ordering types is a fine thing to do, but then again I enjoy Haskell and type-related shenanigan.)

Comment: Your question is essentially, "could Python's designers have designed something about the language differently?" And the answer is, yes, they could have. (PS: the rich comparison operators are preferred in latter versions of Python 2.x as well.)

Comment: @delnan: Yep sorry, I just quickly checked in 2.7

Comment: @delnan, thanks that was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it would be against the Zen of Python: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

`Explicit is better than implicit.`

If you look at the following line of code in isolation:

```
issubclass(a, b)
```

It's perfectly obvious that `a` and `b` are variables containing classes and we are checking if `a` is a subclass of `b`. And if they happen to not contain classes, you'll know.

But looking at this

```
a < b
```

Would not tell you anything. You need to examine the surrounding code to determine they contain classes before you know that we are checking if the class in `a` is a subclass of `b`. And if say a=5 and b=6 it will still run "fine".

But Python is flexible, so if you *really* want this, you can implement a base type with such behaviour as you've shown.

Actually - as an aside -  the prevalence of overloading operators in C++ for example is a significant drawback of the language (at least in my eyes) because when you see `a + b` it might as well launch a nuclear missile for all you know.... until you check types of a/b, look up the class implementation and `+` operator overload implementation (if any... and if not see if the parent class has any.... and if not see if the parent parent...)

Comment: In C++, operator overloading is even more fun because you can overload operators with free functions - they don't need to be defined by the class in question.

Comment: Abuse of operator overloading is a straw man. You can make things do something deceptive in any language. Good luck figuring out what a+b does in Python.

Answer (score 2):

One advantage in bold:

> `issubclass(class, classinfo)`
>
> Return true if class is a subclass (direct, indirect or virtual) of classinfo. A class is considered a subclass of itself. **classinfo may be a tuple of class objects, in which case every entry in classinfo will be checked.** In any other case, a TypeError exception is raised.

Another is that it's descriptive; not everyone using Python is a mathematician.

Comment: As you can see from my implementation above, an `__lt__` method could have handled a tuple of types.

Comment: Yes, but then you're *really* getting into non-obvious territory. Remember, your definition of "intuitive" is not everyone's definition of "intuitive". A lot of people don't even know what "partial ordering" means. `issubclass` makes it clear that you're working with the type system, as opposed to what a lot of people consider "standard values" - in many people's minds, those two are distinct (even though in Python they aren't, truly).

Comment: Amber: I do know what a partial ordering is and even with that knowledge the syntax is just totally non-intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the advantage is non-functional. The only technical difference is that `<` is infix.

But this question isn't about technical stuff. It seems to be about semantics and ease of reading.

Using `<` would denote order. Although class hierarchy can be interpreted as "orderable", it'll always be an approximation. A non-obvious one, for many people.

Using `issubclass` is clearer, still simple and doesn't lend itself to no other interpretation other than what it actually does: check if an `object`/`classinfo` is a subclass of `class`.

Plain, simple, unambiguous, effective. Those are the advantages. Maybe you don't/can't take advantage of them. But that's already personal taste.